# How to parse XML into php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, xml-parsing

How to convert this to php output?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>    
    <employee>
          <name>Mark</name>
          <age>27</age>
          <salary>$5000</salary>
          </employee>
          <employee>
          <name>Jack</name>
          <age>25</age>
          <salary>$4000</salary>
          </employee>
          <employee>
          <name>nav</name>
          <age>25</age>
          <salary>$4000</salary>
    </employee>
```

Comment: means how i got xml file output in php?

Comment: You can use DomDocument to create and parse xml http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Mark - 27 - $5000
Jack - 25 - $4000
nav - 25 - $4000   , i need to get output like this

Comment: <?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( 'test1.xml' );
  
$employees = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "employee" );
foreach( $employees as $employee )
{
  $names = $employee->getElementsByTagName( "name" );
  $name = $names->item(0)->nodeValue;
  
  $ages= $employee->getElementsByTagName( "age" );
  $age= $ages->item(0)->nodeValue;
  
  $salaries = $employee->getElementsByTagName( "salary" );
  $salary = $salaries->item(0)->nodeValue;
  
  echo "<b>$name - $age - $salary\n</b><br>";
  }
?>

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( 'test1.xml' );//xml file loading here

$employees = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "employee" );
foreach( $employees as $employee )
{
  $names = $employee->getElementsByTagName( "name" );
  $name = $names->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $ages= $employee->getElementsByTagName( "age" );
  $age= $ages->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $salaries = $employee->getElementsByTagName( "salary" );
  $salary = $salaries->item(0)->nodeValue;

  echo "<b>$name - $age - $salary\n</b><br>";
  }
?>
```

// the out put like this
    Mark - 27 - $5000 
    Jack - 25 - $4000 
    nav - 25 - $4000

Answer (score 3):

I don't really get your question, but f you want to parse xml using php, you can use the xml extension : http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php

You will then be able to print out the data to your liking

Comment: Mark - 27 - $5000
Jack - 25 - $4000
nav - 25 - $4000 i need to get output like this

Answer (score 3):

You can see this discussion: You can find the answer there:

[Best XML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/188414/1288172)

And if you are looking for the solution in CodeIgniter. These couple of links might help

1. [Parsing XML files using CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259688/parsing-xml-files-using-codeigniter)
2. http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2009/03/parsing-xml-file-using-codeigniters-simplexml-library/

Comment: <?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( 'test1.xml' );
  
$employees = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "employee" );
foreach( $employees as $employee )
{
  $names = $employee->getElementsByTagName( "name" );
  $name = $names->item(0)->nodeValue;
  
  $ages= $employee->getElementsByTagName( "age" );
  $age= $ages->item(0)->nodeValue;
  
  $salaries = $employee->getElementsByTagName( "salary" );
  $salary = $salaries->item(0)->nodeValue;
  
  echo "<b>$name - $age - $salary\n</b><br>";
  }
?>

Answer (score 3):

Think your XML is lacking a root entry, so, parsing will stick.  However, that issue aside, lookup simplexml_load_file and simplexml_load_string. Those are the simplest ways to access XML in a PHP-style structure.

In your XML sample, I've inserted a generic 'records' entry. For example:

```
$t = <<< EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>    
<records>
    <employee>
          <name>Mark</name>
          <age>27</age>
          <salary>$5000</salary>
    </employee>
    <employee>
          <name>Jack</name>
          <age>25</age>
          <salary>$4000</salary>
    </employee>
    <employee>
          <name>nav</name>
          <age>25</age>
          <salary>$4000</salary>
    </employee>
</records>
EOF;

$x = @simplexml_load_string( $t );

print_r( $x );
```

Function is warning-suppressed since you probably don't want validation warnings.  Anyhow, at this point, the parsed XML will look like this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [employee] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [name] => Mark
                    [age] => 27
                    [salary] => $5000
                )
            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [name] => Jack
                    [age] => 25
                    [salary] => $4000
                )
            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [name] => nav
                    [age] => 25
                    [salary] => $4000
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: its working but i need output like; Mark - 27 - $5000
Jack - 25 - $4000
nav - 25 - $4000

Comment: You just have to echo with your formating: `foreach ($x[employee] as $employe){ echo $employe['name'] .' - ' . $employe['age'] . ' - ' . $employe['salary'] . ' ';}`

Comment: How to give CSS to the output of this xml ??;<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( 'test1.xml' );
  
$employees = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "employee" );
foreach( $employees as $employee )
{
  $names = $employee->getElementsByTagName( "name" );
  $name = $names->item(0)->nodeValue;
  
  $ages= $employee->getElementsByTagName( "age" );
  $age= $ages->item(0)->nodeValue;
  
  $salaries = $employee->getElementsByTagName( "salary" );
  $salary = $salaries->item(0)->nodeValue;
  
  echo "<b>$name - $age - $salary\n</b><br>";
  }
?>

Answer (score 0):

@pp19dd says your missing a root node, your current xml is in-valid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

    <document>
        <employee>
            <name>Mark</name>
            <age>27</age>
            <salary>$5000</salary>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <name>Jack</name>
            <age>25</age>
            <salary>$4000</salary>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <name>nav</name>
            <age>25</age>
            <salary>$4000</salary>
        </employee>
    </document>
```

**Parse with DomDocument and compile into a temp array**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->load('data.xml');

$employees = $dom->getElementsByTagName('employee');

foreach($employees as $employee)
{
    $names = $employee->getElementsByTagName( "name" );
    $name  = $names->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $ages = $employee->getElementsByTagName( "age" );
    $age  = $ages->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $salaries = $employee->getElementsByTagName( "salary" );
    $salary  = $salaries->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $tmp[] = array(
        'name'  =>  $name,
        'age'  =>  $age,
        'salary'  =>  $salary
    );
    continue;
}
```

**Output to a view(list/table)**

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach($tmp as $staff):?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $staff['name'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $staff['age'];?></td>
        <td style="color:red;"><?php echo $staff['salary'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</tbody>
</table>
```