# how to extract data from an xml file as input for my code

Tags: java, c, xml

How do i extract data from an xml file and store them into data structures in my code to use them? I might be using java or c for my coding but i need to extract data from an xml file conveniently to go ahead

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing XML files using CodeIgniter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259688/parsing-xml-files-using-codeigniter)

Comment: Needs to be retagged as java because the statement of posting says "I might be using java or c"

Answer (score 1):

If your XML files have a corresponding schema (or schemas), then the easiest way is to use [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) to generate Java classes that can be used for both marshallng (turning Java objects into XML) and unmarshalling (read XML into Java objects).

Even if you don't have a schema, it is still worthwhile, but in this case you have to manually create and annotate the Java classes that corresponds to your XML structure.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as one of the possible options you can use [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), there is a great amount of documentation available on the official PHP website. Examples included.